# Making the peace of the code immutable

Tags: scala

I can't figure out how I can make the following code be immutable:

```
def function123(str: String, mapVal: Map[String, String]) = {
    var str1 = str
    mapVal.keySet.foreach({x => 
       str1 = str1.replaceAll(/*some pattern involving x*/, mapVal.get(x).get)})
    str1
}
```

I can suspect I'd use `foldLeft` or a nested method with parameter-accumulator, but these are only my thoughts.

So how do I do that?

Comment: Usually you make objects immutable, from your two parameters string is already immutable and Map, you can copy and return a new map each time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**foldLeft**

You have a loop here.

Immutable version of loop with side-effects is `foldLeft` with all side-effects replaced with next state creation:

```
val result = mapVal.foldLeft(str){case (state, (key, value)) => 
  state.replaceAll(/*some pattern involving key*/, value)
}
```

To work in immutable environment each iteration of loop should return value and take the result of previous iteration as parameter. This is exactly what `foldLeft` is.

**Recursion**

The other solution is recursive method. You should extract loop iteration to method and make this method to call next iteration in the end:

```
def function123(str: String, mapVal: Map[String, String]) = {
  @tailrec def loop(state: String, pairs: List[(String, String)]): String = pairs match {
    case Nil => state
    case (key, value) :: tail =>
      val nextState = state.replaceAll(/*some pattern involving key*/, value)
      loop(nextState, tail)
  }
  loop(str, mapVal.toList)
}
```

**Mutable loop -> immutable**

To make code with mutable loop to be immutable you should extract all values implicitly involved in changes within loop into some kind of state (single state-object for `foldLeft` or bunch of parameters for recursive method) and then produce a new state based on previous in the end of each iteration.

Comment: `Immutable version of loop with side-effects is foldLeft with all side-effects encapsulated in state` -- what side effects do you mean?

Comment: @MariusKavansky: See the last update. I mean all side effects. All actions that involves reassignment any value. Any reassignments of `var` or mutations of mutable objects. Note that `I/O` and message sending are operations with side-effects.

Comment: sorry, it's not clear yet. there is no "var" in your first example and, thus, any side-effects. where are they?

Comment: and can please show me how I can make your first approach become immutable without any side-effects?

Comment: Both my examples are immutable equivalents of your code. There is a single `var` in your code - `var str1` and there was a side-effect in you code: `str1 = `. I've replaced it with creation of new state.

Comment: that's what I'm asking -- you said there are side effects in your example. however, there is no "var" there. how is it possible? if there is a creation a new state (which your examples have) then it doesn't have any side-effects, isn't that so?

Comment: @MariusKavansky: `all side-effects encapsulated in state` fixed: "with all side-effects replaced with next state creation". Is it clear now?